# Word to describe people who blindly believe accusations

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I can’t for the life of me remember what this word is or if it even exists.
I’m thinking of a word that would describe medieval era peasants who are religious and make and believe accusations of witch craft or demons etc. Such a word could describe the people in the town of Salem during the infamous witch trials.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Gullible", perhaps?

Comment: For your specific context, ***superstitious*** probably fits best.

Comment: At first, I thought you were talking about "lemming," but after reading your details, I know exactly what you're talking about.  It's coming to me.  It seems to me that the word is somehow related to the word "villager," like "villain" is.  Or it's some word that originally meant "townsperson."  Maybe something having to do with "province," "provincial."  Ah, I can't think of it.  Maybe that shook something loose for you.  Anyway, I've put in the request.  It'll be popping out of my brain hopefully sooner than later.  I'll be checking back and answering if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Credulous "having or showing too great a readiness to believe things." Oxford American Dictionary

The visitor counted on the credulous nature of the villagers when he told them he could detect evil in their children.

Answer (score 0):

It is "Superstitious"----- one susceptible to belief or beliefs not based on human reason or scientific knowledge but based on dogmas and mystical or supernatural powers. Such a person is dogmatic and freety.

Answer (score 0):

They are **unquestioning**

> Accepting something without dissent or doubt.
>
> > *‘an unquestioning acceptance of the traditional curriculum’*

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unquestioning)